# Non-restoring signed integer division post-corrections

Tags: algorithm, math, binary, integer-division, divider

I cant figure out the post-corrections to non-restoring integer division. For some reason I keep getting cases where I correct where no corrections are needed or don't correct when needed

heres pseudocode of the algorithm. `Dividend` is 16bits and others 8 bits. By `Dividend_Sign`, `Remainder_Sign` I mean their MSB is 1, so they are negative by 2's complement.

```cpp
LoopCounter = 8;
do {
    Shift Dividend Left with 0 in LSB;

    if (Dividend_Sign XOR Divisor_Sign) {
        Shift 0 into Quotient;
        DividendHighByte = DividendHighByte + Divisor;
    } else {
        shift 1 into Quotient;
        DividendHighByte = DividendHighByte - Divisor;  // subtraction by 2's complement
    }
} while (loopCounter != 0);

Remainder = DividendHighByte;

// here i do the Quotient conversion
invert MSB;  // shifted out anyway. Probably should be used for overflow check, not important atm.
shift 1 into Quotient;
```

now im at a point where i basically have the right answer, it just needs to be post-corrected in one way or another... OR not post-corrected at all. Im not sure what all the correction cases are. right now i have something that isnt working half the time, but here it is anyway:

```cpp
if (Dividend_Sign XOR Remainder_sign) {     // diff signs so correct
    if (Remainder_Sign XOR Divisor_Sign) {  // diff signs just add
        Remainder = Remainder + Divisor;
        Quotient = Quotient - 1;
    } else {
        Remainder = Remainder - Divisor;
        Quotient = Quotient + 1;
    }
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29

http://www.acsel-lab.com/arithmetic/papers/ARITH17/ARITH17_Takagi.pdf

Comment: Could you elaborate on, or at least enumerate, the cases that don't work?

Comment: atm found -10:2  and -10:-2 are correct precorrection and the correction messes it up. -16:4 needs to correct, but doesnt. I think it has something to do with them having a  0 remainder.

Comment: Please explain the requirements that you need for the remainder once the correction is complete (ignoring for the moment HOW that correction is accomplished).

Comment: Well i need it to be a correct binary representation of the remainder. Not sure what you mean by requirements for it to be correct- Quotient*Divisor + Remainder = Dividend. I correct when the remainder has a different sign than the dividend originally. -10:2 produces 11111011 Quotient, 0000000 remainder pre-correction. 11111100 Q, 11111110 remainder post-correction. In this case i don't need to correct, but the algorith calls for it anyway.

Comment: yields incorrect results. Should be corrected, but aren't since remainder and dividend are both negative. I couldn't help but notice that again, there was a cycle with the remainder 0.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10395/discussion-between-ollosaurus-rex-and-scott-hunter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm works, the problem is 2s complement has a negative zero. If the final remainder is 0 no corrections are ever necessary. But the algorithm must detect a 0 remainder within cycles and if one is encountered corrections are always necessary.

Just added a 0 remainder flag and did this:

```
if (!Remainder.isEmpty() && (zeroFlag || (Dividend.Sign() XOR Remainder.Sign())))
      ...do corrections
```

Comment: 2's complement doesn't have a negative zero. 1's complement does and so does sign-magnitude.

Comment: This is actually a valuable answer on post-corrections in signed non-restoring division scheme. Usually case for zero partial remainder or final remainder is not considered at all, for example http://www.google.ru/search?q=computer+arithmetics+behrooz+parhami+pdf , though normal postcorrection is considered there. Without zero-remainder post-correction cases the algorithm would eventually give wrong results which differ +-1 from true answer (I'm now only considering quotient, not resulting remainder). The described fix seems to return correct quotient in 100% cases.